# How to show Profile Icon next to Large Navigation Bar Title in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, image, swiftui, profile

I am developing an App that supports multiple Profiles. I really like the way Apple displays the `Profile Icon` next to the `Large Navigation Bar Title` in all their Apps. See the Screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot Example]

My Question is the following:

- Is it possible to achieve this in `SwiftUI`? And if so, how?
- If it's not possible in pure `SwiftUI`, how can I achieve it including `UIKit` Code?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 23):

I solved this by using [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect), to "Introspect underlying UIKit components from SwiftUI".

Here is an example of a view:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var lastHostingView: UIView!
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(1 ... 50, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("Index: \(index)")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Large title")
            .introspectNavigationController { navController in
                let bar = navController.navigationBar
                let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: BarContent())
                
                guard let hostingView = hosting.view else { return }
                // bar.addSubview(hostingView)                                          // <--- OPTION 1
                // bar.subviews.first(where: \.clipsToBounds)?.addSubview(hostingView)  // <--- OPTION 2
                hostingView.backgroundColor = .clear
                
                lastHostingView?.removeFromSuperview()
                lastHostingView = hostingView
                
                hostingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    hostingView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bar.trailingAnchor),
                    hostingView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bar.bottomAnchor, constant: -8)
                ])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bar content & profile picture views:

```
struct BarContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("Profile tapped")
        } label: {
            ProfilePicture()
        }
    }
}

struct ProfilePicture: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(
                LinearGradient(
                    gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .blue]),
                    startPoint: .topLeading,
                    endPoint: .bottomTrailing
                )
            )
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

*The `.frame(width: 40, height: 40)` & `hostingView.bottomAnchor` `constant` will need to be adjusted to your needs.*

And the results for each option (commented in the code):

| Option 1 | Option 2 |
| --- | --- |
| View sticks when scrolled | View disappearing underneath on scroll |
| [image: Result - Option 1] | [image: Result - Option 2] |

Comment: Thank you for this awesome Answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. However, I encountered a Problems with `Option 2` *(Option 2 is the behavior I would like to use)*: When navigating to a second View that also uses a `Large Title`, everything is going great, but when navigating to a View with `Inline Title` and then go back, the Profile Icon appears right on the Large Title of the original View, not on the right end anymore. How can I fix this Error? Then, your solution is perfect;)

Comment: @christophriepe I have been trying for hours at this point trying to figure this out - hopefully I can fix it soon!

Comment: Would be great. This solution is so clean. This is the only problem.

Comment: @christophriepe So there doesn't appear to be a great solution, which isn't really hacky and looks super bad for option #2. Option #1 is the best way, and I don't think having the overlap when scrolling should be too much of a problem. You could temporarily hide `BarContent()` by using `.onAppear` and `onDisappear` from the destination content instead (icon won't be on destination view). I think the best solution is to simply go with option #1 as it works much better. After all, we are trying to access a private view here so the solution for option #2 is a little bit hacky.

Comment: @christophriepe I think the real problem with option #2 is in the first view you expect the profile icon to be underneath, but then above when navigated to the next view. It doesn't really work very well. However, option #1 I think is really good and clean and definitely worth doing. Option #1 is also arguably better to use since you don't have to swipe to the top to click your profile icon, but I guess it is preference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unluckily, Option #1 is not an option since I have a bunch of trailing navigation bar items in many views. Also, when using Option #1, the Navigation Back Button is not clickable anymore since the custom view is above it.

Comment: I'll go with Option #2 anyway I think. I only have a few Views with inline style, these I can change. However, when having a SearchBar inside the Navigation Bar, the Profile Icon View gets displayed inside the search bar view. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: @christophriepe Fixed the back button for option #1 (see edit). I don't know when I'll be able to solve the problem of option #2 not working well when navigating, but I will fix it when I know how.

Comment: While it's still not an ideal solution, you've earned the bounty. If you can think of something else in the future, I would be happy if you share it here.

Comment: This is the only answer that works with tap gesture.

Answer (score 5):

## Without NavigationView

I done this with pure SwiftUI. You have to replace the `Image("Profile")` line with your own image (maybe from Assets or from base64 data with UIImage).

```
HStack {
    Text("Apps")
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
    
    Spacer()
    
    Image("Profile")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        .clipShape(Circle())
}
.padding(.all, 30)
```

This products following result:
[image: result displaying big bold word "Apps" and then my example profile pircture]

## With NavigationView

Let's assume that you have `NavigationView` and inside that there's only `ScrollView` and `.navigationTitle`. You can add that profile image there by using overlay.

```
NavigationView {
    ScrollView {
        //your content here
    }
    .overlay(
        ProfileView()
            .padding(.trailing, 20)
            .offset(x: 0, y: -50)
    , alignment: .topTrailing)

    .navigationTitle(Text("Apps"))
}
```

Where ProfileView could be something like this:

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("Profile")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .clipShape(Circle())
    }
}
```

The result will be like this...

[image: result of the code above]

...which is pretty close to the App Store:

[image: gif displaying App Store behaviour]

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. However, this is not quite was I was looking for. When scrolling now, the Title will just disappear from the Top Edge without transforming in an Navigation Bar with an inline title. Any Idea for a solution that keeps this feature?

Comment: @christophriepe Oh, my bad. I edited my answer to better fit to your needs. Please take a look.

Comment: Awesome! Basically, this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you have any Idea how to let the Icon disappear just like the Title behind the Navigation Bar and not fade out?

Comment: And even more important: The Profile Icon needs to be a Button. However, when adding the padding and the offset, the Button ist not clickable anymore. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It is working only if the NavigationView color is .clear, which is the default. It is a nice solution though. Thank you!

Comment: The Profile icon is not clickable as soon as the overlay is used, because Navigaton bar covers the image.